# Delete Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello Dear Programmers,

I've defined a forum based system in which a logged-in user is allowed to delete his posts, recently I've had my delete button smooth and going, but after trying to add up some more scripts for my edit button ( button that allows users to edit their posts ), my delete button lost it's functionality, so far the codes makes total sense, I've checked it few times, but the delete is not working as it used it too ...... snippet below is the ajax part of the code;

```
        $(".btn-delete").on("click", function() {

        var selected = $(this).attr("id");
        var pageid = selected.split("del_").join("");
        var confirmed = confirm("Are You Sure You Want to Delete This Post?!");

        if(confirmed == true) {

        $.get("ajax/pages.php?id="+pageid);
            console.log('trying to get ajax/pages.php?id='+pageid);

        $("#page_"+pageid).remove();

        }

        alert(selected);    
    });
```

and here is is my forum page in which i'm calling it;

```
      <a href="#"  id="del_<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

any help is appreciated buddies, thanks in advance.

Comment: Any console error? is your button getting fired? have you put your click event in `document.ready()`?

Comment: Well, no console message at all, and no I didn't put it on document.ready(), should I ?

Comment: your code working fine by passing static id . see [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/v2L90k5a/) on jsfiddle. check your ajax page (ajax/pages.php) response with firebug or console

Comment: Yea bro! I've got it to work yo !, send the code as an answer so I can label as an answered,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is ready. jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside "$( document ).ready()" will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute, and since there were no "$(document).ready(function()", jQuery Could not detect the state of readiness.

The following snippet is how the code looks like after adding "$( document ).ready()" ;

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  

$(".btn-delete").on("click", function() {  
    var selected = $(this).attr("id");
    var pageid = selected.split("del_").join("");
    var confirmed = confirm("Are You Sure You Want to Delete This Post?!");

    if(confirmed == true) {

        $.get("ajax/pages.php?id="+pageid);
        console.log('trying to get ajax/pages.php?id='+pageid);

        $("#page_"+pageid).remove();

    }

   // alert(selected);    
  });
 });
```